# Sublime text 2 Unable to save hidden files on windows

Tags: windows, sublime-text-2

In windows, upon saving changes to a file that's hidden, sublime text 2 throws the error "Unable to save".

[image]

The good commenter below confirms it's only me who's having this problem..

I've tried reinstalling Sublime text, deleting all settings in `%AppData%\Sublime Text 2` but still no luck.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

edit: http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/104563-error-when-saving-files-with-hidden-attribute-set/

edit: I think I may have found the root cause, it's python 2.6 which sumlime uses to save files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215716/ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied-when-trying-to-open-hidden-file-in-w-mod

Comment: Your problem isn't that the file's hidden, it's that the file has its read-only flag turned on.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Are you confirming that you've tried this and succeeded? [Doesn't seem to work for me..](http://i.imgur.com/IOL4aL8.png)

Comment: Yes. As the first thing I thought of, I tried it. Hidden files have no special meaning outside of Windows Explorer that's relevant. Can you alter the contents of the file with Notepad or another application?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard yeah, notepad works just fine. Weird..

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Are you sure you're using sublime text **2** on windows?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. However, the post you linked to in the last hours made me think a little more about the problem. It turns out that, if the file is hidden, Sublime resets the hidden flag (which correlates to the Win32 API call Python does that you mentioned). This in turn makes write access to the file attribute necessary for Sublime to write a file. I tried to disable attribute writing privileges on the file's Security Tab and, with the hidden flag, managed to get the same error as you. However, I fail to see a case where this would willingly happen, but it is another thing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Normally hidden files have no special meaning outside of Windows. However if the file is hidden, Sublime resets the hidden flag (which correlates to the Win32 API call Python does that you mentioned). This in turn makes write access to the file attribute necessary for Sublime to write a file.

When disabling writing attribute privileges on the file's Security Tab and, with the hidden flag, it shows the same error as you. However, it's difficult to say when this would willingly happen.